# MySQL conditional user permissions

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, permissions

**The question… Is it possible to add MySQL permissions to only allow to select fields based on permissions?**

Example:

1. User `user1` can only select/insert/delete from the `users` table where the column `instance` is equal to `1` (1 being passed via PHP).
2. User `user2` can only select/insert/delete from the `users` table where the column `instance` is equal to `2` (1 being passed via PHP).

**Here's the background info:**

I'm creating an application with the same code base being used for multiple sites. Conditions within the app load different layouts. The multiple sites are using the same database because most information can be shared between sites. A user that registers on one site must also register on another site (this is how we want it because the sites are "by invitation only")

What I'm thinking of doing is to have users table: id, email, password, instance. The instance column would have the id of the site.

On the application layer every time I need to select/insert/delete from this table I append instance = [site_id] to the query... example: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '' AND instance = [site_id];`

Comment: Since the application side is taking care of adding instance = x to the queries the MySQL is just an added security in case a query accidentally does not have instance = x.

Comment: just test your code, there is no such thing as 'accidentally' in coding

Comment: Thank you for all your answers and the lengthy discussion. I will contemplate the solution and award it appropriately. @pyrate I agree there is no accidental code. With multiple developers sometimes it's hard to track this sort of thing in the long run. Another reason for the question is to reassure the companies we deal with that there is a technical security boundary/restriction to accessing user information between sites. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible from what I know, MySQL doesn't allow conditional users.

Use one user for both sites and modify your all queries accordingly to your 'instance'. So every time you query something site-specific you add `WHERE instance = $site_id`.

Answer (score 3):

no, the permission is per table,db,server,etc but not for rows, however there is a solution, you can use view tables and set permission to user, for example

```
mysql> CREATE VIEW test.v AS SELECT * FROM t where email = '' AND instance = [site_id];
```

just create 2 view tables and grant access to those users

here is the [Mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)

Comment: 2 different views is pain in the neck every time you add new columns/change structure, isn't it?

Comment: @pyrate if you change the table structure I think will be a pain on any application, however if you the changes doesn't affect how you create the view, there is no problem at all

Comment: you're absolutely right, creating views without looking selecting particular columns shouldn't be affected. But when you select particular columns in a view (and usually you do) - you'll need to change both of your views (and not just both if you have a dozen  websites using one code base), not only the table.

Comment: @pyrate agree, because the view will be pointing to something that doesn't exists, but the same will happen with store procedures, functions, triggers, etc.

Comment: good point. Still - I don't think different views are the best option here: every time you add new site - you'll need to create new views with only 1 different variable. Doesn't sound like a best coding practice.

Comment: Great solution! I thought about this but I'm concerned with performance of mysql views. Such as joins on view rather than tables. I would need to read more about how table locking and other performance joys are performed on views... If performance isn't that much an issue I will consider this solution.

Comment: @iDev247 the performance of a view table is the same that make a query to the original table, but it will take a little bit of space to save the 'view table'.  Big companies does that with developer to avoid Jr developer mess up, or for security reason use a lot of view tables.

Comment: @pyrate if you have 50 sites, do you think that 50 view tables is too much??, you are sacrificing space but you'll be improving security

Comment: @iDev247 performance is absolutely the same, but views here are overkill. Let's say you have small application - 100 tables. You create 20-50 views from this. You'll need to create same amount of exact same views (but with different instance = site_id) for second site. It's not going to improve security and will just give you extra trouble. Views are awesome, but creating separate views because you need to change one variable a bad coding practice.

Comment: @jcho360 we're not talking about 1 view per site. Even tiny site will have a dozen of views. You are talking about duplicating views instead of passing a variable thru queries/sprocs. I don't see how is it going to improve security.

Comment: @pyrate there is no way where you can specify a user modify only a few rows, the only way is with view tables or if you prefer you can do the same with triggers, procedures and function giving them restricted access per user.  The security of course can be improve because I can hide important fields in the view, like credit cards, password, etc, that are not necessary for some users to know it.

Comment: @jcho360 sorry, but this argument doesn't make any sense. If you don't want to display column - do not select it. What you are talking about sounds more like using a view with a stored procedure logic.

Comment: @pyrate you got me wrong way, let's pretend you have 20 developers and all of them work with a table that have username,password,creditcard, id, address, etc etc, would you let that all the developers were able to see all that info?, so you create VT to classify which user can see which data

Comment: @jcho360 if project has 20 developers you will have development, staging and production environments with separate databases. I think this discussion is pointless to go with further, we both made ourselves clear enough. Merci.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL does not facilitate using permissions to lock down certain rows based on the MySQL user that is connected to the database.

If you have users that you want to limit in such a way, it is probably best to not give them direct database access, but have them connecting through another layer.

Using a view is not a good idea - every user would have to use different queries (referencing their own personal view) to accomplish the same things.  If you were just limiting the *columns* that a user could see (instead of the rows), a view would be a good solution.

It is possible to use stored procedures to accomplish something like what you're looking for:

```
# This table already exists in your schema
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `instance` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO `user`(`id`,`email`,`instance`) 
    VALUES ( NULL,'wat@lol.com','1');
INSERT INTO `user`(`id`,`email`,`instance`) 
    VALUES ( NULL,'huh@bwu.com','2');
INSERT INTO `user`(`id`,`email`,`instance`) 
    VALUES ( NULL,'no@yes.lol','1');

# This would be a new table you would have to create
CREATE TABLE `user_instance` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `instance` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_instance` (`user`,`instance`)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO `user_instance`(`user`,`instance`) VALUES ('user1','1');
INSERT INTO `user_instance`(`user`,`instance`) VALUES ('user2','2');

# This is a stored procedure that might accomplish what you want
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `p_get_users`()
BEGIN
    SELECT `user`.`id`, `user`.`email`
    FROM `user`
    WHERE `user`.`instance` IN(
        SELECT `instance` 
        FROM `user_instance` 
        WHERE `user` = USER());
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```